# Youtube API for fetching recommended free audio tracks

Tags: youtube

YouTube site provides an option 'Edit Video' for an uploaded videos. Here, it gives an option to Swap the Audio track with free audio tracks available in the library. For this. it also lists the recommended tracks.

Is there any API available to get the list of recommended tracks for a given video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no APIs available to fetch the list of recommended audio tracks [corresponding to the feature Swapping Audio tracks]. Youtube doesn't have any plans to add it in the near future.

Please refer the following link:
http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/5ea3811971e4f73e/5ae6e26cafd6ee45?lnk=gst&q=Youtube+API+for+fetching+recommended+free+audio+track#5ae6e26cafd6ee45